# onblur with ActiveAdmin, possible?

Tags: javascript, forms, activeadmin

It is possible to use onblur event with an ActiveAdmin form ?

Something like that :

```
f.input :contact, :as => :radio, :collection => ["slide", "formulaire de contact", "map", "video"], :class => "select", :onblur => "myFunction();"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f.input :contact, as: :radio, collection: [...], input_html: {class: "select", onblur: "myFunction();"}
```